# Unit test on object, not class

Tags: java, junit, testng

How can I run a unit test (with JUnit, TestNG, whatever does the job), on an object, not a class? (*object* meaning: a class instance)
The unit testing framework should provide the same annotation possibilities like with JUnit, TestNG, etc.. With `@Before`, `@Test`, etc..

Like:

```
class StartupBean {
    @EJB   // <-- Initialized with Auto-Discovery by JavaEE
    TestIT object;

    void run() {
        // Exactly what I want
        // ("UnitTester" as a placeholder for whatever behaves like JUnitCore().run(...) on objects):
        UnitTester.test(object);

        // *Not* this, using a class, instead of an object:
        new JUnitCore().run(TestIT.class);
    }
}

class TestIT {
     @Before
     public void setUp() { ... }

     @Test
     void run() { ... }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "on a class" ? on static methods?

Comment: that doesn't clarify anything, you just repeat what you said. unless you are talking about static methods, you can't call the methods on anything but an instance

Comment: Further clarified

Comment: "the class should have the same annotation possibilities"? those annotations are JUnit, not related to your class. I think you're looking way too far

Comment: I made that part clearer. I hope all uncertainties are gone?
I just had bad experiences with to long text, going into too much detail. Almost nobody reads them.

Comment: You are testing objects already my man @Jan

Comment: ok ... to check your latest update ...
Why would you even want to do something like that?

Comment: Because I want JavaEE to take care of all the EJB initialization, like mentioned in the first comment. "new MyClass()" wont do that. And I don't want to use JNDI lookups since they have proofen to behave differently than an @EJB lookup. Therefore defeating the purpose of integration testing the real system.